# Which distant country/s in Europe have had Hindu Gods?

Tags: vedas, gods, history, vedic-gods

[image: Mitanni Treaty]Apart from inscription on tablet in Turkey at Boghazkoye, traces of the great Arya or Vedic gods exist in which other countries? What were their names? What was their character? Vedic civilisation stretched from Turkey to India.
(Turkish: Boghazkoye=Boghazkale, boghaz narrow pass, kale, koy, kuei castle, castle controlling the pass)

Comment: The tablet in question from Turkey isn't from the Vedic civilisations but from the Mittani people. The Mittani, Armenians, Kurds, Greeks, Iranians, Celts, Etruscans, Germanic, Baltics, Slavs & Vikings did worship the Vedic deities (of sorts) before taking up Christianity & Islam but since they are devoid of the Veda, they can't be considered as part of the Vaidika civilisation.

Comment: Question wording is "have had". It important to know the hindu gods covered vast territories.